# Using ORM from TreeFrog Framework

Tags: c++, qt, orm, web-frameworks, treefrog-framework

I've met Qt based [TreeFrog Framework](http://www.treefrogframework.org/). I'd like to use its ORM subsystem in my Qt 5.5+ based project. Does anyone have hints for adapting it for using in a desktop console application (just for CRUD operations)? Please, don't advise other frameworks. TreeFrog Framework will be used in full (REST + ORM) and ORM mode for the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework author wrote: it would be hard to decouple the ORM because it's combining with the framework strongly. Unit test program is a console application.TF_TEST_MAIN macro may be a hint. See http://www.treefrogframework.org/documents/test